# Mostrar incompleto los datos de una consulta en html

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Resulta que al hacer una peticion a la base de datos e intentar mostrar los datos de un registro, este solo me muestra la primera palabra de cada registro, por ejemplo, los apellidos, solo me muestra el primero, y pasa lo mismo con el nombre y la direccion, me tocó usar un placerholder para que me mostrara los datos porque de otra forma, no se visualizan.
Este es el codigo html. En la terminal, el Json trae todos los datos, pero en la vista de html, no los muestra todos.Los datos estan completos en la db, al usar un label, me los muestra todos, pero si uso un form, no. Y necesito poder editar los valores si los quiero cambiar.

```
<div>
<form class="lista" action="" id="formregistro">
<div class="tipo">
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Tipo Documento</label>
<input type="number" name="PerTipoDocumento" placeholder= <%= data.PerTipoDocumento %>>
</div>

</div>
<div class="identificacion">
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Documento</label>
<input type="number" name="PerDocumento_Persona" placeholder= <%= data.PerDocumento_Persona %>>
</div>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Nombre  </label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerNombre"><%= data.PerNombre %></label>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Apellidos  </label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerApellidos" placeholder= <%= data.PerApellidos %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Correo Electronico</label>
<input type="email" readonly name="PerEmail" placeholder= <%= data.PerEmail %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Móvil</label>
<input type="number" readonly name="PerMovil" placeholder= <%= data.PerMovil %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>EPS</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerEPS" placeholder= <%= data.PerEPS %>>
</div>
<br>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Telefono fijo</label>
<input type="number" readonly name="PerTelefono" placeholder= <%= data.PerTelefono %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
<input type="text" name="PerFecha_Nacimiento" placeholder= <%= data.PerFecha_Nacimiento %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Direccion de Residencia</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerDireccion" placeholder= <%= data.PerDireccion %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Barrio</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerBarrio" placeholder= <%= data.PerBarrio %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>País Residencia</label>
<input type="text"  readonly name="PerPais_Residencia" placeholder= <%= data.PerPais_Residencia %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Departamento o Estado</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerDepartamento_Residencia" placeholder= <%= data.PerDepartamento_Residencia %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="campo">
<label>Municipio Residencia</label>
<input type="text" readonly name="PerMunicipio_Residencia" placeholder= <%= data.PerMunicipio_Residencia %>>
</div>
<div class="campo" id="genero">
<label>Genero</label>
<input type="genero" readonly name="PerSexo" placeholder= <%= data.PerSexo %>>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="control">
<div class="aceptacion" id="aceptacion">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>¿Acepta los términos y condiciones de la página?</label>
</div>
<div class="tratamiento" id="tratamiento">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>¿Acepta el uso y tratamientos de  sus datos personales?</label>
</div>
<div class="notificacion" id="notificacion">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>¿Desea ser notificado via correo electronico?</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega el código de cómo lo habías intentado antes de usar placeholders.